# SQL query to get grandparent-parent-child relationship of an element with minimum use of JOINS

Tags: sql, left-join, inner-join

I have 2 tables and I want to display the child, parent and grandparent by using SQL query with **minimum use of JOINS** (preferably avoid JOINS as my actual table has hundreds of thousands of records).

Table1 -

```
| id   | Name               
|:-----|-------
| 1    | ab                           
| 2    | cd                         
| 3    | ef                          
| 4    | xy 
| 5    | zx
| 6    | mn
```

Table 2 :

```
pop   | kid

|:-----|------
| 2    | 1                           
| 3    | 2                         
| 5    | 4                         
| 2    | 6
```

output -

```
child  parent  grandfather
1          cd       ef
2      ef
4      zx
6      cd
```

eg : 1 is child of 2 (cd) and 2 is child of 3 (ef), hence the output -> 1          cd       ef

Comment: See: [Why should I provide an MCRE for what seems to me to be a very simple SQL query?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-a-minimal-reproducible-example-for-a-very-simple-sql-query)

Comment: @Abhi . . . Please explain what "minimal use of joins" means.

Comment: @GordonLinoff  maximum 1 join, we can use sub queries.

Comment: https://www.postgresqltutorial.com/postgresql-recursive-query/

Comment: @Abhi it seems that somewhere you have gotten a misconception of JOIN. In most cases join is the **fastest** method. In fact if you search through SO you will discover that converting to join form other methods is the solution for slow queries. After all join is the heart of data retrieval in the relational model - that is what RDBMS do. Do not shy away from joins embrace them.

Answer (score 3):

You do need to join. Other approaches, like using a recursive query, will be less efficient. Joins are not necessarily harmful for performance if you have the right indexes in place.

```
select t1c.id, t1c.name, t1p.name, t1g.name
from table1 t1c
left join table2 t2c on t2c.kid = t1c.id
left join table1 t1p on t1p.id  = t2c.pop
left join table2 t2g on t2g.kid = t1p.id
left join table1 t1g on t1g.id  = t2g.pop
```

**[Demo on DB Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=87c495664c798e9bcb2eba2a43510482)**:

```
id | name | name | name
-: | :--- | :--- | :---
 1 | ab   | cd   | ef  
 2 | cd   | ef   | null
 4 | xy   | zx   | null
 6 | mn   | cd   | ef  
 5 | zx   | null | null
 3 | ef   | null | null
```

Comment: massive upvote for the demo, made it much clearer (for a newbie, like me) :-)